# Is it correct to call this Gaussian Mixture Model?

Tags: video-processing, background-subtraction

Some poeple claim their background subtraction algorithms use Gaussian Mixture Model, 
but when I read the code, I find they actually use only one component, 
and as a result EM algorithm (or its approximated version) is not taken to fit the model. 
An example can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/276355). 
This configuration is commonly adopted when the background is strictly static, 
e.g. the scenes without swaying tree branches.

More specifically, their methods use some simple criterion: 
a pixel is classified as foreground if it satisfies

$$
\sum_{c \in C} w_c\frac{|I_c(x,y)-\mu_c(x,y)|}{\sigma_c(x,y)} > \text{Threshold}
$$

where $C$ is the set of channels (RGB, HSV, etc.) and $w_c$ is the weight of channel $c$. 
Technically there is no **mixture** distribution any more. 
Do you think it's still appropriate to call this model GMM?